# Open website in new tab without loading page interface in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension. My code from content.js opens 10 tabs by link(for example window.open('google.com/search?q=***')). My problem is that sites take too long to load. Is it possible to open a certain site without loading styles, pictures, videos and maybe some scripts for faster page loading? I only need html and some text

Comment: You can use declarativeNetRequest to always disable sub-resources on those sites. An alternative is to call `window.stop()` in your content script that runs inside those sites.